# pthread loop overwriting pointers

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am writing a simple barbershop C/C++ project with classes, pthreads, mutex, and conds but I am running into an issue when I create a new customer object in a loop:

```
void BarberShop::simulate() {
barber.start(); // start the barber
int custId = 1;
while(1) {
    Customer c(custId, *this);
    customers.push_back(c);
    c.start();
    sleep(3);
    custId++;
}
```

}

```
void Customer::start() {
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &Customer::run, this);
}

void* Customer::run(void *ptr) {
    Customer* data = reinterpret_cast<Customer*>(ptr);
    while(1) {
        printf("Customer %d running...\n", data->id);
        sleep(3);
    }
}
```

When I run this program it will create the threads fine but whenever I make a new thread it will overwrite the id's in the other threads. Output:

```
Customer 1 running... 1 sec
Customer 1 running... 2 sec
Customer 1 running... 3 sec
Customer 2 running... 4 sec
Customer 2 running... 4 sec
```

In the loop I say:

```
Customer c(...);
```

Does that not create a new instance each loop iteration? Why would the subsequent threads overwrite this?

**Update**

```
class Customer
{
private:
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    static void* run(void *args);
    int id;
    BarberShop *bs;
public:
    Customer(int _id, BarberShop &_bs);
    ~Customer();
    void start();
}; 

Customer::Customer(int _id, BarberShop &_bs) {
id = _id;
bs = &_bs;
}
```

**Update 2: With pthread id's**

```
Customer 1 running...[3066383168]
Customer 2 running...[3057990464]
Customer 2 running...[3057990464]
Customer 3 running...[3049597760]
Customer 3 running...[3049597760]
Customer 3 running...[3049597760]
Customer 3 running...[3049597760]
Customer 4 running...[3049597760]
Customer 4 running...[3041205056]
Customer 4 running...[3041205056]
Customer 4 running...[3041205056]
Customer 5 running...[3041205056]
Customer 4 running...[3041205056]
Customer 5 running...[3032812352]
Customer 5 running...[3032812352]
```

Comment: you're not storing the customer id in your class as a static member variable are you? Could you show the code for your constructor?

Comment: It's always the same customer, at the same place, on the same stack.

Comment: Copying or moving `pthread_mutex_t` is not defined behavior. You should disable copy construction and assignment of `Customer` - which of course means you can't put them in a `vector`. Use `vector<Customer*>` instead.

Comment: @Martin James... doh! yes good spot. +1

Comment: @martinJames & Casey: Guys, both good info... you should post as answers +1'd them both

Comment: @Casey new to C++, not exactly sure what this means. "Disable copy constructor and assignment" what other way is there? Example?

Comment: @userXXX: Look at the link in my post. Disable copy constructor means making the copy constructor private to the class so that it effectively can't be used :)

Comment: @Jimbo Alright sounds good, I will read up on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following segment

```
while(1) {
    Customer c(custId, *this);
    customers.push_back(c);
    c.start();
    sleep(3);
    custId++;
}
```

class instance `c` is local to the scope of the while loop. At the end of each iteration of the loop, `c` is destroyed.

So, when you do `customers.push_back(c)` a **copy** of the class is taken (see [***(default) copy constructor***](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/)) and added to the customers list. This means that when you do `c.start()` the copy that you pushed onto your vector has *not* been started, only the instance local to the loop. At the end of the loop iteration of the loop `c` is destroyed. The loop starts again and a new `c` is created.

EDIT: 
See Martin James' and Casey 's comments as to why the behavior you're seeing is happening

Comment: Actually... I am wrong... this is exactly the issue. Instead of c.start() I needed to: customers[customers.size()-1].start(); THANKS!

Comment: I think you're missing a couple of the points made by Casey and MartinJames.

Answer (score 2):

Stack-based auto objects and multiple threads are err.. 'not harmonious in all situations' :)

You could use a vector of Customer*, as suggested by Casey.  If you are going to pass objects to threads by reference, dynamically-allocate them with new.  This gets round the problems of non-copyability of synchro objects etc. and ensures that each thread gets its very own *object.  The thread gets ownership and, if it needs to terminate before the process is terminated, needs to delete the passed *object.

Alternatively, vector::emplace the Customer object into the vector so that the auto/stack Customer goes away.